# Loading iAd banner from the top

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad, adbannerview

I've managed to implement iAd into my app and the banner loads from the bottom, I'm unsure how to get it to load from the top instead. I've tried a number of things but I can't seem to crack it. Can anyone help please?

The code I have:

```
- (void)layoutAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;

    CGRect bannerFrame = self.bannerView.frame;
    if (self.bannerView.bannerLoaded) {
        contentFrame.size.height -= self.bannerView.frame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    } else {
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? 0.25 : 0.0 animations:^{
        self.contentView.frame = contentFrame;
        [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
        self.bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
    }];
}
```